# Laravel: Add "required" rule if wildcard matches "gb" in languages.*.description

Tags: laravel, validation

Right now I have this rule:

```
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'languages.*.description' => ['string', 'required'],
        ];
    }
```

What I need is to exclude `required` if the wildcard equals `gb`. I could do something like this but it feels clunky:

```
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'languages.no.description' => ['string', 'required'],
            'languages.nl.description' => ['string', 'required'],
            'languages.gb.description' => ['string'],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's clunky, if this often changes what you could do is create an array that holds your languages.

```php
protected $languages = [
    'no' => true,
    'nl' => true,
    'gb' => true,
];

public function rules(): array
{
    $rules = [];
    foreach ($this->languages as $language => $isRequired) {
        $rules["languages.$language.description"] = $isRequired ? ['required', 'string'] : ['string'];
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you put the gb rule last e.g. :

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'languages.*.description' => ['string', 'required'],
        'languages.gb.description' => ['string'],
    ];
}
```

Though this does not seem documented and may change in the future.